# How to get the Builds for a project using OData in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powerbi, odata, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to get all the builds for a project using Odata for Azure Devops. However I found there was an endpoint for that `https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/Builds` but while trying the same for my Project I'm getting the below error

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Resource not found for the segment 'Builds'.","typeName":"Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataUnrecognizedPathException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.OData.Core","typeKey":"ODataUnrecognizedPathException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

Is this endpoint not available anymore. Or is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: Change `Builds` to `PipelineRuns` and try it again. Please consider [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) If it's helpful to resolve your issue. So that members with similar issue can easily find the useful info and we can archive this thread, thanks~

Comment: Thanks @LanceLi-MSFT . It works. Is there any way to get the others details like who triggered the build and the build comments using oData query. Possibly a replacement for the Azure Rest API `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1`

Comment: Sorry but as i know those are not supported. It can show the detail about how the build pipeline is triggered like `RunReason":"Manual"`, but it can't show the detail about who manually does that. When we use above url without filters, it actually display all the fields/properties the url supports, it's obvious that the properties you want are not included in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this endpoint not available anymore. Or is there something wrong
>   with my query?

The entity set `Build` has been renamed. You can check [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/888993/view.html) from our User Voice forum.

All entity sets and entity properties with names starting with `Build` will be renamed to start with `PipelineRun`.

For e.g. `Builds` entity set will be called `PipelineRuns`, `BuildId` entity property will be called `PipelineRunId`.

So what you should use is : `https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/PipelineRuns`. It works on my side :)

Comment: This helped me a lot the other way around. My server doesn't support the new endpoint, but all the documentation points to the new one.